# Decrementar um valor Mysql

Tags: mysql

Existe algum atributo MySQL para Decrementar dia , mes , ano ou hora no próprio banco que seria automaticamente.

Ex: coluna-> valor inicial = 15, depois de um dia seria 14

O banco mysql faz isso ???

Comment: Melhor [edit] a postagem e explicar o que quer ao menos com um exemplo claro. Da forma como está, não dá para ter muita certeza do que está procurando. Inclusive por não fazer muito sentido uma operação de data ser contrária a um auto increment, sendo que a natureza do dado é bem diferente. Me parece que sua pergunta remete a um [Problema XY](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/499)

Comment: Ai cara da para entender agora

Comment: @Bacco seria um exemplo um sistema pago depois de um mês de teste  é bloqueada a conta do usuário ate que ele pague.

Comment: Realmente é um Problema XY, sua pergunta se prendeu no jeito que você achou que ia conseguir resolver, e não na súa dúvida real, que é "como bloquear um sistema após um mês de teste" (cuja resposta provavelmente nem passa pelo que está na sua pergunta, bastaria um `IF data > prazo de teste`). A solução realmente seria refazer totalmente a pergunta com sua dúvida real.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De modo automático não tem, mas existe algumas abordagens para fazer isso.

A mais simples é implementar na própria query que faz o update, segue um exemplo:

```
UPDATE tabela SET
    campo1 = 'Teste',
    campoData = DATE_ADD(campoData, INTERVAL -1 DAY)
WHERE
    (id = 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma trigger ou evento (Trigger só ocorre quando uma operação é acionada, tipo insert, delete, update) para executar esta operação diariamente, por exemplo:

```
CREATE EVENT event1
ON SCHEDULE EVERY '1' DAY
DO
-- sua operação aqui, por exemplo:
   UPDATE TABELA SET CAMPODATA = str_to_date( date_format(now(), '%Y%m%d 0200'), '%Y%m%d %H%i' ) - INTERVAL 1 DAY
END
```